# Валидация данных в fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

```
@app.get('/user')
def get_user_products(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    products = select_user_products(user_id, db)
    return {"products": products}
```

Почему выдает ошибку при запросе:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user?user_id=2

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "int_parsing",
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "product_id"
      ],
      "msg": "Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer",
      "input": "user",
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/int_parsing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Хотя при post-запросе все работае как нужно..

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```py
@app.get('/user/')
```

Не разграничивает переменные при запросе из-за пропущенного `/`